# ideal state of SPI MOSI and MISO pins?

Tags: spi, clock

Just wondering , If some how the MOSI and MISO tracks which connects the slave get cut. At that time, its disconnected from the slave.

So if the micro controller tries to read data from MISO pin, what will it read?

Comment: I would rather see a solution that lets the master know the slave is gone, rather than just letting the master read in garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will read whatever the MCU is configured to read on that pin by default. If pulled high or low, then it will read high or low, otherwise it will read as floating.